# drop down using liferay-ui:input-select tag

Tags: liferay-6

I want to customize the "meetups" portlet which is given by liferay.In that portlet now I have to do validation on fields(i.e mark few fields as mandatory) and create a field with drop down and that field has to be mapped to database.
can anyone please say how can i acheive this.

Answer (score 0):

i have acheived the drop down functionality.Now i want to do client side validation using javascript.i am using document.getElementById('title) to retrieve the value.Sometimes it is working,sometimes it is not working.why is this happening